# Recycler view inside Horizontal scroll view not work in android oreo but is working perfectly in below versions

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, horizontalscrollview

the code below does not work for the oreo version android but is working is other versions . i am trying to use horizontal scroll view in this case a user must be able to comment and the other comments is shown by help of recycler view.so i have a problem in this code only for the new version of android .can anyone suggest me ideas regarding the issue.
here is the code

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="none">
    <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="horizontal">
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="175dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:background="@layout/button_background"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            >
            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/userfbpic1"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:src="@drawable/bg"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/current_username"
                android:text="@string/current_username_forcomment"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/background"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                />
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="60dp">
                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/background"
                    android:id="@+id/comments"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:hint="comment here"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerview_comments"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
   </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: Are u see child click time parent scroll disable. I mean recycler view click or drag event u do parent horizontal scrollview scroll set false then it's worked.

Comment: example please ?

Comment: v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

Comment: it didn't work for me ..can i get more suggestions please

Comment: https://medium.com/widgetlabs-engineering/scrollable-nestedscrollviews-inside-recyclerview-ca65050d828a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you put a `RecyclerView` inside a `ScrollView` of the same **orientation** the `RecyclerView` will extend, inflating and putting out all of his children inside the `ScrollView` becoming **unscrollable**. When you drag the view the `RecyclerView` consumes touch events and the `ScrollView` won't scroll, unless you disable `RecyclerView` touch..

Comment: so how do you do that ? @ KeivanEsbati

Comment: My suggestion is to move all the other views inside the recycler as a header view, you will benefit both from better performance and less memory usage. Else you can extend recyclerView and override touch events though it is terrible performance wise.

Answer (score 3):

Add this below code in your touch listener on recyclerview

```js
recyclerview.addOnItemTouchListener (new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() 
{
    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

        int action = e.getAction();
        switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                rv.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
    
});
```